# Date Range Search

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, date-range

hi im having trouble in my date range search cause it fetch wrong result

ex: im searching 04/01/2013 to 04/02/2013 supposedly that the result will show the data from 04/01/2013 to 04/02/2013 these dates but it fetch it wrong data

this is my form

```
<form  method="post"id="myform" action="index.php" >
        <label for="from">Sales Date from :</label>
        <input name="startfrom" type="text" id="startfrom" class="datepicker form-control"/>
        <label for="to">Sales Date to :</label>
        <input name="to" type="text" id="end" class="datepicker form-control"/>
        <label>Outlet Name:</label>
        <select name="OutletName" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option value="">--</option>
            <?php
            error_reporting(0);
            include 'config.php';
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY OutletName ORDER BY OutletName";
                $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
                    echo "<option value='".$row["OutletName"]."'".($row["OutletName"]==$_REQUEST["OutletName"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["OutletName"]."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <label>Category:</label>
        <select name="Category" class="input-sm form-control ">
            <option value="">--</option>
            <?php
            error_reporting(0);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY Category ORDER BY Category";
                $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
                    echo "<option value='".$row["Category"]."'".($row["Category"]==$_REQUEST["Category"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["Category"]."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select></br>
        <label>Product Code:</label>
        <select name="ProductCode" class="input-sm form-control ">
            <option value="">--</option>
            <?php
            error_reporting(0);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY ProductCode ORDER BY ProductCode";
                $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
                    echo "<option value='".$row["ProductCode"]."'".($row["ProductCode"]==$_REQUEST["ProductCode"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["ProductCode"]."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select></br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" id="submit"  />FIND&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
```

and here is my search query

```
if ($_REQUEST["Category"]<>'') {
                                    $search_Category = " AND Category='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["Category"])."'";   
                                }
                                if ($_REQUEST["ProductCode"]<>'') {
                                    $search_ProductCode = " AND ProductCode='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["ProductCode"])."'";  
                                }
                                if ($_REQUEST["OutletName"]<>'') {
                                    $search_OutletName = " AND OutletName='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["OutletName"])."'"; 
                                }

                                $search_groupby = "GROUP BY CategoryID,OracleCategory,ProductCode ORDER BY CategoryID,OracleCategory,ProductCode ";

                                if ($_REQUEST["startfrom"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["end"]<>'') {
                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE SalesDate >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["startfrom"])."'AND SalesDate <='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["end"])."'".$search_OutletName.$search_Category.$search_ProductCode;
                                } else if ($_REQUEST["startfrom"]<>'') {
                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE SalesDate >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["startfrom"])."'".$search_OutletName.$search_Category.$search_ProductCode;
                                } else if ($_REQUEST["end"]<>'') {
                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE SalesDate <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["end"])."'".$search_OutletName.$search_Category.$search_ProductCode;
                                }else {
                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE ECRNo>0 ".$search_OutletName.$search_Category.$search_ProductCode;
                                }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<input name="to" type="text" id="end" class="datepicker form-control"/>
```

To

```
<input name="end" type="text" id="end" class="datepicker form-control"/>
```

The name of the `datepicker` should be `end` as you have used `$_REQUEST["end"]` in the date receiving end.

**EDIT**

Use this query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(str_to_date(SalesDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) >= '".strtotime(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["startfrom"]))."' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(str_to_date(SalesDate, '%d/%m/%Y'))<='".strtotime(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["startfrom"]))."'".$search_OutletName.$search_Category.$search_ProductCode;
```

If you are using GROUP BY on `salesDate` field use it this way `GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(str_to_date(SalesDate, '%d/%m/%Y'))`

**EDIT 2**

Substitute all occurance of

`SalesDate` to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(str_to_date(SalesDate, '%d/%m/%Y'))`
and
`$_REQUEST["startfrom"]` to
 `strtotime(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["startfrom"]))`
and
`$_REQUEST["end"]` to
`strtotime(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["startfrom"]))`

Comment: thanks an i edited it no but there is a another problem my SalesDate is varchar how can i convert it datetime or date?

Comment: here it is
`$sql = "SELECT CategoryID,OracleCategory,str_to_date(SalesDate, '%d/%m/%Y'),OutletName,ProductCode,Category,MealType,SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity1,SUM(NetPrice) AS NetPrice1 FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE str_to_date(SalesDate, '%d/%m/%Y') >= '".date('d-m-Y',strtotime(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["startfrom"])))."' AND str_to_date(SalesDate, '%d/%m/%Y')<='".date('d-m-Y',strtotime(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["end"])))."'".$search_OutletName.$search_Category.$search_ProductCode.$search_groupby;`

Comment: i also change this 
`if (date('d-m-Y',strtotime(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["startfrom"])))<>'' and date('d-m-Y',strtotime(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["end"])))<>'') {`

as you said

Comment: Sorry change `date('d-m-Y',..)` to `date('d/m/Y'..)` and  What is on `$search_groupby` ?

Comment: here

`$search_groupby = "GROUP BY CategoryID,OracleCategory,ProductCode ORDER BY CategoryID,OracleCategory,ProductCode ";`

Comment: still doesn't fetch any data

Comment: Check my edit now and also what is the format of date stored in your database in terms of %d %m %y?

Comment: it is varchar and it stores the value like this 04/01/2013